# Не суммирует в excel

Tags: excel, формулы

Есть столбец G. В нём использую формулу =ЕСЛИ(ЕПУСТО(H1);"0";"1"), проверяю столбец Н и если в нем есть что то, то в столбец G записываю 1 в противном случае 0 после чего хочу подсчитать сумму в столбце G формулой =СУММ(G1:G10). не считает сумму. Я так понял полученные значения 1 или 0 воспринимает как булиевы?? Вроде всё банально но не получается...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для подсчета количества непустых ячеек существует функция `СЧЁТЗ()`. Используя ее, можно избавиться от ненужных промежуточных вычислений, например:

```
=СЧЁТЗ(H1:H10)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 =ЕСЛИ(ЕПУСТО(H1);"0";"1")
```

Вам нужно для подсчета указывать не символ "1", а целое 1

```
=ЕСЛИ(ЕПУСТО(H1);0;1)
```

Тогда можно суммировать

Comment: СПАСИБО! Оба варианта помогли, но да если есть спец функция, через неё будет правильнее работать. Ещё раз спасибо.